# Pythonic way of getting method arguments into a dict

Tags: python

I'm writing an api and was wondering what's the most pythonic way to do the following.

I'm writing a bunch of methods to do various web calls, the arguments mostly translate into post data keys and values.

The way I've been writing it so far is mostly like this;

```
def doSomething(self,param1,param2,param3):
    payload={"param1":param1,
             "param2":param2,
             "param3":param3}
    return self.request("do/something",payload)
```

This already has the draw back of having to repeat the parameter names which are subject to change, but this pattern isn't too bad.

The following case is what got me trying to think of a better way. In this case there are 4 optional arguments for the call

```
def doSomethingElse(self,param1,param2=None,param3=None,param4=None,param5=None):
    payload= {"param1":param1}
    if param2:
        payload["param2"]= param2
    if param3:
        payload["param3"]= param3
    # ... etc ...
    self.request("do/something/else",payload)
```

My first thought was to do this:

```
def doSomethingElse(self,param1,**params):
    payload = {"param1":param1}
    payload.update(params)
    self.request("do/something/else",payload)
```

or even:

```
def doSomethingElse(self,**payload):
    self.request("do/something/else",payload)
```

Although the second one is nice and simple, the method can be called without the non-default argument. But in both cases I lose the method signature when using the api and the user won't know what the parameters are (I know I could write the expected signature in a docstring but I'd rather prevent misspelt keywords getting sent).

I'm thinking there must be a nice pythonic solution to do this, any ideas?

### EDIT

I think a key point which I didn't make clear enough is that the arguments are getting sent in  post data in a call, and I want to make sure only those keys can get sent, like in the first example of `doSomethingElse`, you can't send anything other than those 5 named parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply

```
def get_payload(ldict):
    return {k:v for k,v in ldict.iteritems() if k != 'self' and v is not None}

class fred(object):
    some_class_var = 17
    def method(self, a, b=2):
        payload = get_payload(locals())
        print payload
```

which gives

```
>>> f = fred()
>>> f.method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: method() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> f.method(2)
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
>>> f.method(2, b=3)
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}
>>> f.method(5, b=None)
{'a': 5}
>>> f.method(2, b=3, c=19)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: method() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
>>> help(f.method)

Help on method method in module __main__:

method(self, a, b=2) method of __main__.fred instance
```

which I think matches your criteria.  The next step would be to use a decorator (probably with either wraps or the decorator module to preserve the signature) so that payload was computed and then passed, but I don't know if `@payload` would be all that much better than `payload = get_payload(locals())`.  Note that using `locals()` this way, it needs to be done at the start.

I second the feeling that this isn't exactly the best way to prevent unwanted nuclear attacks, though.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about locals! This is a pretty nice solution, keeping the signature intact

Answer (score 4):

The Pythonic way is to name the parameters when you call the function, not in the function signature:

```
def doSomething(self, **kwargs):
    self.request("do/something/else", kwargs)

doSomething(param1=3, param2='one', param3=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
def doSomethingElse(self, param1, **params):
    payload = {"param1": param1}
    for name, value in params.items():
        if value is not None:
            payload[name] = value
    self.request("do/something/else", payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several such functions, you can do as following:

```
class Requester(object):
    def __init__(self, tobecalled, *allowed):
        self.tobecalled = tobecalled
        self.allowed = set(allowed)
    def __call__(self, otherobj, **k):
        for kw in k.iterkeys():
            if kw not in self.allowed:
                raise ValueError("unknown argument(s) given: %s" % kw)
        otherobj.request(self.tobecalled, **k)
    def __get__(self, outside, outsideclass):
        return lambda **k: self(outside, **k)

class Outside(object):
    def request(self, method, **k):
        print method, k
    do_one_thing = Requester("do/one/thing", 'param1', 'param2')
    do_nonsense = Requester("do/nonsense", 'param3')
    simple = Requester("simple")

o = Outside()
o.do_one_thing(param1=1, param2=2)
o.do_nonsense(param3=12)
o.simple()
try: o.do_one_thing(rparam1=1, param2=2)
except ValueError, e: print e
try: o.do_nonsense(gparam3=12)
except ValueError, e: print e
try: o.simple(whatever=12)
except ValueError, e: print e
```

What happens here? We create a `Requester` object which plays the role of a method: if we put it in another class (here: `Outside`), it can be called in a way that it also gets a reference of an object which it is called on. What I call `outside` here is "the outer `self`", as I call it now. And then, it returns a lambda which calls the object itself, just like a function does. And there, the arguments are checked for validity, and if that passes, we do the call on the "`outside`"'s `request()` method.